# Why is this gutenberg custom format button only available from the toolbar as a dropdown?

Tags: javascript, block-editor, formatting

I have a very simple custom format button for Gutenberg. JS code is as follows:

```
(function ( wp ) {
    // Create our button.
    var lqdNotesButton = function( props ) {
        return wp.element.createElement(
            wp.Editor.RichTextToolbarButton, {
                icon: 'editor-code',
                title: 'Blank It',
                onClick: function () {
                    props.onChange( wp.richText.toggleFormat(
                        props.value,
                        { type: 'lqdnotes/blankit' }
                    ));
                },
            }
        );
    };

    // What the button does
    wp.richText.registerFormatType(
        'lqdnotes/blankit', {
            title: 'Blank It',
            tagName: 'span',
            className: 'lqdnotes-blank-it',
            id: lqdNotesButton,
            edit: lqdNotesButton,
        }
    );
} )( window.wp );
```

It works but you have to click on a down arrow to the right of the bold/italic/link buttons to see it.

Is there an option to force the button to appear on the toolbar itself and not the dropdown?

Comment: Same problem for me. have you found an answer to this problem ?

Comment: I didn't find an answer but I did get a response...though I can't for the life of me find it atm. I was told that this was operating as intended, they want to keep the UI as simple as possible. I'd still like to find a way around it but haven't had more time to spend on it recently.

Answer (score 2):

Old question but an up-to-date answer could help someone: instead of using `RichTextToolbarButton` you have to use the `BlockControls` component. This way your button will appear *before* the other styling buttons.

ESNext working example (from the [official documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/format-api/)):

```
import { registerFormatType, toggleFormat } from '@wordpress/rich-text';
import { BlockControls } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { ToolbarGroup, ToolbarButton } from '@wordpress/components';

const MyCustomButton = ( { isActive, onChange, value } ) => {
    return (
        <BlockControls>
            <ToolbarGroup>
                <ToolbarButton
                    icon="editor-code"
                    title="Sample output"
                    onClick={ () => {
                        onChange(
                            toggleFormat( value, {
                                type: 'my-custom-format/sample-output',
                            } )
                        );
                    } }
                    isActive={ isActive }
                />
            </ToolbarGroup>
        </BlockControls>
    );
};

registerFormatType( 'my-custom-format/sample-output', {
    title: 'Sample output',
    tagName: 'samp',
    className: null,
    edit: MyCustomButton,
} );
```